# Filtering e-mails with Exim and Virtual Domains

Tags: email, exim

I have Exim set up on a CentOS machine and it has virtual domains (not Vexim) set up on it.  I'm trying to figure out how to create a filter to forward emails from one address to another with a subject rewrite.

IE,

"Subject" for support@mydomain.com

becomes

"[Support] Subject" for user@mydomain.com

I've tried the .forward file, but it doesn't seem to have any effect.  The mail directory for users are in:

```
/var/www/user_name/data/email/mydomain.com/user1/
/var/www/user_name/data/email/mydomain.com/user2/
```

This is what I have so far, but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

```
# Exim filter
if $h_to: is "support@mydomain.com" then
  headers add "New-Subject: [Support] $h_subject:"
  headers remove subject
  headers add "Subject: $h_new-subject:"
  headers remove new-subject
  unseen deliver "user@mydomain.com"
endif
```

Has anyone done this before?  I can't find anything on Google about virtual domains with filtering.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that your To: header *is* not equal to "support@mydomain.com" but *contains* "support@mydomain.com".

I don't know what should be the difference between virtual users and "real" users concerning filtering. So just follow a guide/tutorial/manual about the Exim filter language: http://exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/filter.html